# How to add Android and iOS configurations after creating a Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-web

I created a Flutter project in Android Studio. In the steps, I just selected 'Web' and now I also want Android and iOS in my project, but I don't know how to add those directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the project in your ide and in terminal enter

`flutter create .`

note that after create there is a period (full stop) which will create android, ios and web whichever isnt present in the project.

Or if you want to add specific platforms use

```
flutter create --platforms=android .
```